# JQuery Sortable get Target item

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a table with the following structure:

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>
        <button id=“elem_id”>Move</button>
    </td>
    <td>
        
    </td>
</tr>
```

With this script:

```
$('tbody').sortable({
        handle: '.drag_handle',
        group: 'nested',
        animation: 600,
        ghostClass: 'drag_drop_class',
        fallbackOnBody: true,
        swapThreshold: 0.65,

        onEnd: function (evt) {

            var btn = evt.item.firstElementChild.firstElementChild;

            let id = btn.id;
            let oldIndex = evt.oldIndex;
            let newIndex = evt.newIndex;
            
            //TODO: Em vez do index da linha tenho de obter o id do destino


            let component_name = btn.getAttribute('data-component');
            // alert("[" + component_name + "] Alterou id=" + id + " da pos[" + oldIndex + "] para a pos[" + newIndex +"]");

            //TODO: Emitir um evento para o componente livewire da tabela de modo a atualizar
            Livewire.emitTo(component_name, 'reorder', id, newIndex);

        }
    });
```

**I have access to the element/item that was dragged**, but now **I need the element/item that was dropped in to**, I've tried a lot of stuff but nothing worked.

I have access to the index but that won't help me because the Data Table I'm using uses pagination and I need to get the position (its a property) of the item by id.

The project I'm working on uses this scripts:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Sortable/1.10.2/Sortable.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-sortablejs@latest/jquery-sortable.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example will help you. I could found an onEnd function within Sortable Jquery Ui.
HTML

```html
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="name1">Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

JQuery

```js
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
  update: function( event, ui ) {
    var item = ui.item;
    var target_prev = ui.item.prev();
    var target_next = ui.item.next();
    console.log('item', item);
    console.log('target_prev', target_prev);
    console.log('target_next', target_next);
  }
});
```

Just watch the console.log at your Developer Tools.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I can't seem to get the update function working, nothing happens, it seems the function is not firing for some reason

Comment: I've updated my post with the scripts the project I'm working on uses

Comment: With your scripts nothing happens if I try a jsfiddle. You are not using jquery ui

Comment: Can I do it without JQuery UI? The sorting and onEnd function are working

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the project I'm working on does not use JQuery UI. It uses **SortableJS**. 
The equivalent code to JQuery UI I found, was the following:

```
onEnd: function (evt) {
        var current = evt.item;
        var prev = evt.item.previousElementSibling;
        var next = evt.item.nextElementSibling;
}
```

For anyone with the same problem just console.log() this vars.